# Error when launching GraphQL Architect against remote neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graphql

I'm trying Neo4j GraphQL Architect graph app for the first time (v0.0.26)

I successfully installed it to Neo4j Desktop 1.4.3 (on Mac 10.15)

When I open it against my operational remote db, I get a dialog that says:

> Error 0! Boolean cannot represent a non boolean value: "true"
>
> Error 1! Boolean cannot represent a non boolean value: "true"

Any advice?

Comment: I have the same problem - any progress?